# Need sql query

Tags: sql, postgresql

**table shows**: 
showid,
tutle,
link
show status
runtime
classification.
**table episdes**:
episodeid, showid, episodeNumber,seasonNumber,airDate,title.

Hello, i need sql query to select title serial and count episodes which already released(edisodes.airDate - date release episode)
please help me) thanks who help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sub query could be used there. E.g.

```
select s.title, s.serial, e.count
from shows s, (select showId, count(*) as count 
                from episodes 
                where airDate <= current_timestamp
                group by showId) e
where s.showId == e.showId
```

Comment: This would return one row per show?  Didn't you comment that you're looking for all episodes per show?

Comment: Its return all show and count released episodes current show.

Comment: If that's what you're after, consider accepting the answer (the green V below the vote buttons, to the left of the answer)

Answer (score 2):

```
select  s.title
,       s.serial
,       e.title
,       sum(case when e.airDate <= current_timestamp then 1 end) 
            over (partition by s.title, s.serial)
from    shows s
left join
        episodes e
on      e.showid = s.showid
        and e.airDate <= current_timestamp
```

Comment: its display only one show and total for all released episodes.
i need a query which select all shows in table shows and total released episodes like e.showid = s.showid

Comment: Ok, changed to return all shows, and the number of released shows using a window function